# Equivalent of Postgres's STRING_TO_ARRAY in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this function where I take a string and split it into an array of words. It works great in Postgres but I want to convert it to SQLAlchemy and I haven't been able to find a good alternative to STRING_TO_ARRAY. Are there any good work arounds that people have found?

Here is my basic query for reference:

```
SELECT type, 
 UNNEST(STRING_TO_ARRAY(description, ' ')) AS word                                                                                    
 FROM item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SQLAlchemy's documentation on [SQL and Generic Functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/functions.html), you should be able to use the function by name directly even if SQLAlchemy doesn't know about it.

> Note that any name not known to func generates the function name as is - there is no restriction on what SQL functions can be called, known or unknown to SQLAlchemy, built-in or user defined.

```py
from sqlalchemy import select, func, Table, Column, MetaData, String

metadata_obj = MetaData()

item = Table("item", metadata_obj, Column("description", String))

stmt = select(
    func.unnest(
        func.string_to_array(item.c.description, " ")
        ).label("word")
    )

print(stmt.compile(compile_kwargs={"literal_binds": True}))

# SELECT unnest(string_to_array(item.description, ' ')) AS word
# FROM item
```

This remains a PostgreSQL specific query, but I don't see how to make it agnostic with both `UNNEST` and `STRING_TO_ARRAY`.